# How to recreate the MobileSync folder in macOS 12+ (Monterey)?

Tags: iphone, backup

## Edit: Solved

I simply had a typo in the location. Fixed.

```bsh
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/Backup
```

## How to Recreate MobileSync Folder?

I deleted my iPhone backups the old fashion way to free up some space...

```bsh
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync
```

But now I can't create new backups... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

It ran the backup process for a long time, as if backing up, but then still says "Never" as the latest backup and the folder wasn't recreated.

So then I tried to recreate the folder...

```bsh
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/Backup
```

But now when I try to run backups I get a message about them being corrupt.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MobileSync folder is in Application Support, so give this a try instead:

`mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/Backup`

so MobileSync is made in Application Support instead of directly in Library.